# VBS | Case - Selection issue

Tags: vbscript, case

I realize this is silly but I've spent too much time trying to figure this out. I just need this block to loop until either "Red", "red", "Blue", or "blue" is typed; (I changed the script to colors to simplify readability).

If there's a better way to do this please elaborate.

```
mbb=MsgBox ("Hit No" ,4, "Start script")
If mbb=7 Then mbt=MsgBox ("Do you like Red or Blue?" ,32, "Choose color")
If mbt=1 Then SOM

Sub SOM
Do
ibb=InputBox ("Please type: Red or Blue")

Select Case ibb
Case "Red"
mbt=MsgBox ("Please explain your answer" ,32, "You chose Red")
Case "red"
mbu=MsgBox ("Please explain your answer" ,32, "You chose Red")
Case "Blue"
mbv=MsgBox ("Please explain your answer" ,32, "You chose Blue")
Case "blue"
mbw=MsgBox ("Please explain your answer" ,32, "You chose Blue")
Case Else
MsgBox "Please Type: Red or Blue"
End Select
Loop Until mbt OR mbu OR mbv OR mbw=1
End Sub

If mbt Or mbu=1 Then mbx=MsgBox ("Rouge" ,4, "Rouge")
If mbv Or mbw=1 Then mby=MsgBox ("Bleu" ,4, "Bleu")
```

Comment: How about converting your `ibb` to lowercase before testing it? `ibb=lcase(ibb)`

Answer (score 1):

You can list multiple spellings in your `Case` statements:

```
Dim sColor
sColor = "red"

Select Case sColor
    Case "Red", "red", "RED"
        MsgBox "Color is Red"
    Case "Blue", "blue", "BLUE"
        MsgBox "Color is Blue"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Color not found"
End Select
```

This will not handle "REd", "ReD", "reD", "rED" and "rEd" values so a more bullet-proof approach is to convert the case using [LCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/9fd71ty9(v=vs.84)) or [UCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/1systdcy(v=vs.84)) functions as Geert Bellekens suggests:

```
Select Case UCase(sColor)
    Case "RED"
        MsgBox "Color is Red"
    Case "BLUE"
        MsgBox "Color is Blue"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Color not found"
End Select
```

The [StrComp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ya4w6fwy(v=vs.84)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function could be another option to make the comparison case-insensitive but it is not as easy to read as a Select Case block:

```
If StrComp(sColor, "RED", vbTextCompare) = 0  Then MsgBox "Color is Red"
If StrComp(sColor, "BLUE", vbTextCompare) = 0  Then MsgBox "Color is Blue"
```

Answer (score -2):

I've managed to find an answer; I realized it would be easier to avoid using the case function for this part of my code. The new format is as follows:

```
'simplified

Option Explicit
Dim a, x, y, w, z

Do
a=InputBox ("Please select hot or cold" ,0, "Type: ""Hot"" or ""Cold"" ")
If a="hot" Then x=MsgBox ("Hot selected" ,64, "Test")
If a="cold" Then y=MsgBox ("Cold Selected" ,64, "Test")
If a="Hot" Then z=MsgBox ("Hot selected" ,64, "Test")
If a="Cold" Then w=MsgBox ("Cold selected" ,64, "Test")
Loop Until x Or y Or z Or w=1
```